# Invokes and Delegates in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, delegates, invoke

Can someone explain the syntax in this block of code?

```
Invoke((MethodInvoker)
    (
        () => 
        {
            checkedListBox1.Items.RemoveAt(i);
            checkedListBox1.Items.Insert(i, temp);
            checkedListBox1.Update();
        }
    )
);
```

I'm using a backgroundworker which needs to update parts of the UI so I used this.  It works, but I don't know what the empty () and => mean.

Comment: You should read this article - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

() and => is a [lambda expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx).

```
Action a = () => { 
    //code here
}
```

is a delegate of type `Action`, which executes the code in the block.

```
Func<string> f = () => {
    //code here
    return "string";
}
```

is a delegate of type `Func<string>`, which executes the code in the block and then returns a string.

```
Func<int, int, string> f = (i, j) => {
    //code here
    return "string"+i+j;
}
```

is a delegate of type `Func<int, int, string>`, which has two int parameters referred to i and j in the code block and returns a string.

Etc...

Answer (score 1):

`() =>` introduces a [lambda expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx).

If the lambda expression received parameters then they would be listed inside the parentheses.  Your lambda is equivalent to

```
void foo()
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

that a [Lambda eExpression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx). The epmty brackets mean that it does not accept any parameters.

Although this snippet seems like it's missing something, don't think it compiles. W

hat Invoke does is call the UI thread. When you do processing, you want to do that on a background thread, and only make short calls to the UI thread. That way you keep the UI responsive.

So this snippts passes a piece of work (add items to the Combobox) to the UI thread to have it done. A  background thread cannot directly do things on the UI thread.

Regards GJ